# removing "href" from the same link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to remove a single link using javascript but it wont work.

```
<a id="yes" target="_blank" href="http://google.com" onclick="this.setAttribute('href', '')">
```

But it whould not open Google as the link is removed.
I can remove other links, using different id-s, but I want the same link Id to be disabled, after the link is opened in new tab

Comment: Easy with JQuery, are you ok to use it?

Comment: Have you tried using `onclick='this.removeAttribute('href'); return false;'` ?

Comment: Yes, It disables the link before the link is opened in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

you can't set same ID to elements - ID must be unique on single page. if you want to remove some specific link you can set them CLASS, and remove by class

in additional to other answers - u can remove href attribute of all visited links than page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a:visited").attr("href", "#")

});
```

or you can remove href attr of now clicked link

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a").click(function(){

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).attr("href", "#")
    }, 300);

  });

});
```

Comment: I know that, I am using different ids for the different links. Imagine i have 20 links with ids like: id1,id2,id3.. etc.. So I want when one ID link is clicked, the link whould open in new tab and the same link id to e disabled in the original page. The other links are not touched.

Comment: before you edit question, were was other info) so you just want disable link that were visited, right?

Comment: so you can see at the @adeneo answer

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want it to work only once? Something like...

```
onclick="if (!this.wasClicked) { this.wasClicked = true; } else { this.removeAttribute('href'); }"
```

But do note that using the inline HTML events (`<a onclick="...">...</a>`) is a very bad practice. Put the event handlers in an external file.

Comment: Yes, but the your code doesnt take the same effect as wanted.

Comment: I guess I do not understand the effect you are trying to achieve, care to explain it?

Comment: Imagine 20 links in my page with different ids. I want when one link is clicked once, to be disabled (doesnt need to be forever, just untill the page is refreshed)

Comment: @user3214661 - does that work for you? Do not forget to accept an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Any onclick handler will execute before the default action does, that's why you can prevent the default action from the event handler.

To complete the default action and *then* prevent it on the next click, just use a property and store a boolean that is checked on the next click :

```
document.getElementById('yes').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (this.prevented) e.preventDefault();
    this.prevented = true;
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4aYR/2/)

To apply that to all links, you'd do

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=anchors.length; i--;) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (this.prevented) e.preventDefault();
        this.prevented = true;
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to apply this logic to all your "a" tags without jQuery. Just run onload

```
var atags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var a = 0; a < atags.length; a++) {
  atags[a].onclick = function() {window.open(this.getAttribute('href'));
                                 this.removeAttribute('href');
                                 this.onclick = null;};

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Awvj4/

To apply this logic to a single a tag, do the following (assuming the "a" tag has an ID of "myatag")

```
document.getElementById('myatag').onclick = function() {
  window.open(this.getAttribute('href'));
  this.removeAttribute('href');
  this.onclick = null;};
```

Comment: I am making this by id this way: <a id="id1" href="link goes here" target="_blank" onclick="removelink('id1')">some text</a> and the javascript function:function removelink(b)
{
  var atags = document.getElementById(b);

  for (var b = 0; b < atags.length; b++) {
    atags[b].onclick = function() {window.open(this.getAttribute('href'));
           this.removeAttribute('href');
           this.onclick = null;};

  }
} but doesnt work

Comment: @user3214661 - I updated the answer with the solution for just one a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I read this as

1. Click the link
2. Link opens new tab/window
3. Link becomes disabled

Therefore

```
function one_time_link(a) {
    var clicked = false; // flag; has the link been clicked?
    a.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (clicked)     // yes
            e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
        clicked = true;  // mark flag as yes
    }
}

// apply to your link (afer it exists)
one_time_link(document.getElementById('yes'));
```

Now the first link click behaves normally, following clicks get cancelled.

---

Multiple links with one flag?

```
function one_time_list(list) {
    var clicked = false, i;
    function click(e) {
        if (clicked)     // yes
            e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
        clicked = true;  // mark flag as yes
    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        list[i].addEventListener('click', click);
    }
}

// and usage
one_time_list([node1, node2, node3]);
```

---

Really need to remove the *href* attribute?

```
node.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var target = this;
    setTimeout(function () { // delay removal until after click complete
        target.removeAttribute('href');
    }, 50);
});
```